# Rewrite Current Chrome Tab URL onto host

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a Google Chrome Extension that will allow a user to search for a website's setting, click on it, then have it take them to that page. I'm currently having difficulty working with the chrome.tabs API.

This is essentially the functionality that I'm missing:

If the user is on https://www.testing.com/settings/this-or-that/whatever I want the extension's search result link to append "/settings/example" only to the host URL. "https://www.testing.com" + "/settings/example"

I was trying to get window.location.host to work, but I've had no luck. My current iteration adds the path onto the current URL. Is there a way for the chrome.tabs.query to pull only the host so that the path can be added-on for each link?

```
chrome.tabs.query(
{active: true, currentWindow: true},
function(tab) {
var newURL = tab[0].url + "/settings/";
chrome.tabs.update(undefined, {url: newURL});
});
```

Comment: Use [URL](http://devdocs.io/dom/url) API: `new URL(tab[0].url).origin + '/settings'`

Comment: How does that fit in context?

Comment: Sorry, I meant, how would rewrite what I have above including what you wrote? :P

Comment: Assign it to newURL, for example: `var newURL = ` and that code.